# How to integrate this?

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

The last integrand I absolutely have no idea how to solve. I tried to use the euler formula but to no avail.

$$\frac { 1 }{ (2\pi ^{ 2 }a^{ 3 }\hbar^{ 3 })^{ 1/2 } } \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ r^{ 2 }dr \;e^{-r/a} \int _{ -1 }^{ 1 }{ d(\cos\theta)\;e^{-ipr \cos\theta/\hbar}} } $$
[Screenshot of the integrand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN9Cl.png)
[The next step in the integration process is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89NfD.png)

Comment: Please post your maths text using [Latex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: When you write $\int_{-1}^1 d\cos\alpha \dots$, do you mean $\alpha$ goes from $-1$ to $1$ (which seems very strange) or $\cos \alpha$ goes from $-1$ to $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the question is about the integral
$$
\int_{-1}^1 d(\cos \theta) e^{ipr (\cos \theta)/\hbar}
$$

This is taken a little out of context (there may be text or formulas
elsewhere in the same source that explain what this integral means),
but a reasonable interpretation seems to be that it means

$$
\int_{-1}^1 e^{ipr u/\hbar} du
$$

where $u = \cos\theta$.
The reason for using the first form of the integral might be that whoever wrote this wanted the effect of a "$u$-substitution" but
wanted to avoid having to break up the flow of equations in order
to define the "$u$" they intended to use.
So rather than define $u = \cos\theta$ and write the integral over the
variable $u$, they wrote the integral *as if* it were an integral over
$u$ where $u = \cos\theta$, but simply wrote $\cos\theta$
in each place where the $u$-substituted integral would have had $u$.

An examination of the lines before and after the integral
(to see what other formulas it comes from, and how it was solved)
could confirm or deny whether this interpretation was meant.

Comment: Yes I see you are hinting to use subsititution. I guess that is the solution. So I would get $$\frac{h}{p r}*e^{-ipru}$$ plug in the boundaries, then you would get sin(p*r/h)

Comment: I think there's also a factor of $\frac1{-i}$ needed there, but yes, that's the basic idea.

Comment: Yes, i forgot that one. So I get zero when I try  put the boundaries..

Comment: So here is my attempt:

Comment: $$ \frac{i*h}{p*r}(e^{-p*r*cos(1)-e^{-p*r*cos(-1)}) = 0

Comment: $$ \frac{ih}{pr}(e^{-prcos(1)-e^{-prcos(-1)}) = 0 $$

Comment: The thing about the substitution is the boundaries are relative to $\cos\theta$, not $\theta$, so they occur where $\cos\theta=-1$ and $\cos\theta=1$. The values $\cos(-1)$ and $\cos(1)$ don't appear anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense! Omg! thanks! I thought the whole time that the new substitution parameter the u function should give out new boundaries, like so g(1) = cos(1), g(-1) = cos(-1)